# Notification is not displaying android

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcast, android-alarms

Am trying to display the notification in a specific time chosen by the user. I wrote the code and it's running perfectly with out any error but the issue is the notification is not displaying in the device. I was used the permissions in Manifest also.. help me with the solution...

**CustomNotification.class**

```
public class CustomNotification extends Activity {
        EditText etNotificationMessage;
    String notificationMessage;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private int pHour, pMinute, pSeconds = 0;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_notification);
        etNotificationMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNotificationMessage);
    }

    public void setNotification(View v) {
        notificationMessage = etNotificationMessage.getText().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pHour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pMinute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, pSeconds);
        /*Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + ":"
                        + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":" + pHour + ":"
                        + pMinute + ":" + pSeconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CustomNotification.this, MyReceiver.class);
          pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CustomNotification.this, 0, myIntent,0);

          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
          Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),"Notification time is"+
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":" + pHour + ":"
                            + pMinute + ":" + pSeconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void startTime(View v) {
        /** Get the current time */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        pSeconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute,
                    false);

        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            pHour = hourOfDay;
            pMinute = minute;

        }
    };

}
```

**MyReceiver.class**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);

    }   
}
```

**MyAlaramService.calss**

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service 
{

   private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),CustomNotification.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.om.timetracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name="com.om.notifications.CustomNotification" >
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try This It will Solve your Problem,

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30452831/4447803

Comment: check that link, it may help to solve your problem , just vote up the answer

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your onReceive() of broadcast receiver

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuild = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("New notification Received");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, CustomNotification .class);
    resultIntent.setAction("FROMNOTIFICATION");
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuild.build());
    mBuild.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: in that where you are passing the user give time, I mean at what time the notification display

Comment: When the broadcast receiver will receive a push notification then only you should display a notification.