# AlarmManager with Notification Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to give the user a notification each day on a certain time so I use an AlarmManager with a notification. I have this:

```
public void check_products(int hour, int minute){=
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setContentText("You need to eat")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(1, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And in the manifest (under the app permissions it says "set an alarm"):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<receiver android:name="com.example.check_products.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

In my main I call the function check_products with the parameters, but whatever I try to do; it doesn't show anything... Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm verry new to android programming so I wouldn't know how to combine the alarmmanager and notifications...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alarm Manager Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this, it may help you

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(sign_in.this,MyNotificationService.class);
pendingintent2 = PendingIntent.getService(sign_in.this, 1,myIntent1, 1);
AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar1Notify = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar1Notify.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar1Notify.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar1Notify.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1Notify.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent2);
long time24h = 24*60*60*1000;
alarmManager1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1Notify.getTimeInMillis(),time24h,pendingintent2);
```

[link For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29509102/4447803)

See above link Your question is Solved .

Comment: I have done exactly same but service is not getting called if application is killed . What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Call receiver in your manifest file.

**Like this**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <receiver android:name="myPackage.AlarmReceiver"
               android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
</application>
```

**Or**

Try this whole example

**MainActivity.java**

```
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent , 0);
            AlarmManager littlefluppy = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            littlefluppy.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 2000, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AlarmReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

    Log.e("alram set.....","");
    }
}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'AlarmReceiver' more..."

Comment: i put whole example try this and let me know

Answer (score 1):

use this Example for reference..

http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html

Use This code for Repeating alarm in it..

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be helpful to mention here.
Optimize your app with Doze and app stand by article from android developers blog help you out.

```
If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() 
 or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
```

you can find source [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)