# How to creat notification in the time limit

Tags: time, android-studio, notifications, limit

I need to the Android app to send notification to remind users at 6am , 7pm , 12am

How can I do that and thank you

I use Android Studio

Comment: post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` for remider.

You can refer code from here

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Thanks very much
I'll watch the article ... and tell you what happened to me

Comment: ohk and also you can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001784/alarmmanager-with-notification-android/31002016#31002016

Comment: I did as you told me, but he became the notification comes all enter the application every minute and this code

Comment: give your code link so that i can able to tell you that from where you put your code.

Comment: ya i show your code what is problem means what do you want ? so that i can tell you

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity.java

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent , 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

AlertReceiver.java

public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    createNotification(context, "Hi", "titl", "Alarm");


}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg , String msgText , String msgAlert){

    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context , 0 ,
            new Intent[]{new Intent(context, MainActivity.class)},0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());



}
```

}

Comment: alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),15000, pendingIntent);

Comment: you can specify your time here like 15000 so its notify after 15 second. so you can specify time according to you

Comment: I want to send a notice every day according to the calendar here:

calendar.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
     calendar.set (Calendar.MINUTE, 20);

Comment: According to the code above.It sends notice after two minutes access to the application

Comment: This code and put it in the onCreate function within the Class MainActivity

Comment: you can write Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead of AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY