# How can I poll a device for location data quicker than WorkManager's 15 min cap?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to poll a device for long/lat every minute or so... I have been researching and found a few things. I was thinking of using:

`PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder()` - however, I have read that it can only execute every 15 minutes at a minimum...

What tech/design pattern are available to me, if I wanted to poll for data in a shorter period?

- Are foreground services my only choice?

Comment: "Are foreground services my only choice?" -- yes.

Comment: yes you service

Answer (score 0):

You can Use any Runnable but when app closed it will not working .

Foreground service is best choice but in android 9+, it will confuse the user

this is the link that show to you how use it:

[Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer)

BUT

I advice you to use an `AlarmManager` that work like work manager but it response better, you can Use Countdown timer for it, link below will help You to use it:

[`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Edited:

sample for open activity with alarm manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_MAIN_ACTIVITY.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ID,
                    intent, 0);

final long DELAY_IN_MILLIS = DELAY_IN_MILLI_SECONDS+ 
System.currentTimeMillis();
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, DELAY_IN_MILLIS,pendingIntent);
```

and there is a full example for you:

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509102/show-the-android-statusbar-notification-in-particular-date)

Comment: Are you able to post any code to help me understand ?